# How to query rows depending on multiple to-many properties?

Tags: sql, join, select, one-to-many

I have one-to-many relation between tables user and tag:

```
Users:
id    username
--------------
 1    Bob     
 2    Alice   
 3    Eve   

Tags:
id   user_id   name
--------------------
 1   1         java         // Bobs tags...
 2   1         java script
 3   1         C#   
 4   2         java         // Alices tags...
 5   3         java         // Eves tags...
 6   3         java script
```

My goal is to extract all users with tags java or java script only, but not users which have java, java script and C# together.

As output of the query I expect to receive following result:

```
Result:
id   username
--------------
2    Alice     
3    Eve
```

I've tried to use query from [SQL one-to-many relationship - How to SELECT rows depending on multiple to-many properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51153040/sql-one-to-many-relationship-how-to-select-rows-depending-on-multiple-to-many), but as I noticed it is a bit different idea behind of it

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One efficient, although lenghty to type, option uses `exists`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where 
    not exists(select 1 from tags t where t.user_id = u.id and t.name = 'C#')
    and exists(select 1 from tags t where t.user_id = u.id and t.name = 'java ')
    and exists(select 1 from tags t where t.user_id = u.id and t.name = 'java script')
```

With an index on `tags(user_id, name)`, this should be very fast.

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt response. It looks like this sample perfectly match with my need. I'll double check it with different cases and will accept the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation logic to get the tags:

```
select t.user_id
from tags t
where t.name in ('java', 'java script', 'C#')
group by t.user_id
having sum(case when t.name = 'C#' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;   -- no C#
```

Bringing in the `user_name` is just an additional join.

Comment: Thank you for prompt response! Could you please additionally advice how this query can be scaled, for instance if I would need to exclude more than few languages?

Comment: @fashuser Ask a new (specific researched non-duplicate) question in a new post, not in comments. But that question is unresearched & asked many times before. [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a `HAVING` would work here:

```
SELECT U.id,
       U.username
FROM dbo.Users U
     JOIN dbo.Tags T
GROUP BY U.ID,
         U.username
HAVING COUNT(CASE T.[name] WHEN 'java' THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE T.[name] WHEN 'java script' THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN T.[name] NOT IN ('java','java script') THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

You could also replace the first 2 `HAVING` clauses with:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN T.[name] IN ('java','java script') THEN T.[name] END) = 2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for prompt response! I'll double check this and will back to you!